# How could Harry use 'Sectumsempra' without learning it?

Tags: harry-potter

In Hogwarts students learn how to cast every spell, and it takes some tries to cast the spell correctly. But Harry was able to use 'Sectumsempra' just by reading it in a book and without knowing what it does?

Is this possible to cast a spell without learning to cast it?

Comment: I mean of course it is else Harry couldn't have done it.

Comment: Horcrux.  Voldemort could cast sectumsempra.  Harry's vespertongue was also from Voldemort, wasn't it?

Comment: There is no evidence that Voldemort cast sectumsempra or even he know about the spell, as it was discovered by Snape.

Comment: Harry is getting better at spell casting.